# Give Python turtle a rectangular shape for ping pong game

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to give a rectangle shape to the turtle in Python, but nothing works from turtle appearance methods.
It says that turtle does not have this attribute.
What can I do?

```
paddle = turtle.Turtle()
paddle.shape("rectangle")

output:
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: There is no shape named rectangle
```

Answer (score 3):

In the turtle module that comes with Python, you can use `shapesize()` to resize any of the existing turtle shape options, `'square'` in this case.  You can stretch or shrink it differently in the two dimensions.  Here's an example paddle that sits in the middle of the screen that's taller than it is wide and can only be moved up and down the screen:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def drag(_, y):
    paddle.ondrag(None)
    paddle.sety(y)
    paddle.ondrag(drag)

screen = Screen()

paddle = Turtle('square')
paddle.speed('fastest')
paddle.shapesize(1, 4)
paddle.setheading(90)
paddle.penup()

paddle.ondrag(drag)

screen.mainloop()
```

You can use two turtles to create these on the left and right of the screen for a ping pong game.

Answer (score 1):

Use `shapesize` method. It accepts 2 arguments. The first value is how many times the height of the figure will be expanded, and the second value is how many times its width will be expanded.

Default size of the turtle is `(20, 20)`.
For example, if you want to create a paddle with 100px height and 20px width you should use the following code.

```
paddle = Turtle("square")
paddle.shapesize(5, 1)
```

*5 * 20 = 100px (height)* 
*1 * 20 = 20px (width)*

Answer (score 0):

**turtle.addshape(name, shape=None)**
There are three different ways to call this function:
name is the name of a gif-file and shape is None: Install the corresponding image shape.

```
screen.register_shape("turtle.gif")
```

Note Image shapes do not rotate when turning the turtle, so they do not display the heading of the turtle! 
name is an arbitrary string and shape is a tuple of pairs of coordinates: Install the corresponding polygon shape.

```
screen.register_shape("triangle", ((5,-3), (0,5), (-5,-3))
```

you should change sizes to have a turtle with the shape of rectangle! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try using:

```
turtle.shape()
```

In the function just put in "square".

Feel free to ask any questions!

Answer (score 0):

I had same doubt and here what I've finally done:

1. I got my turtle object to become a "square",

> turtle.shape("square")

and after I printed out it's shape as coordinates:

> print(turtle.get_shapepoly())

2.After it, I was twitching the coordinates until I got the desired effect. In essence, the end result was:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, Shape
```

SHAPE = ((10, -40), (10, 40), (-10, 40), (-10, -40))

class Paddle(Turtle) :

```
def __init__(self, contour_color):
    super().__init__()
    self.new_shape(contour_color)
    self.setheading(90)

def new_shape(self, contour_color):
    screen = Screen()
    s = Shape("compound")
    poly1 = SHAPE
    s.addcomponent(poly1, "grey", outline=contour_color)
    screen.register_shape("paddle", s)
    self.shape("paddle")
```

I leave here a link to the documentation used. Hope it was of help!

https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.get_shapepoly
[Turtle Graphics Library. Description and link to relevant section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.get_shapepoly%20https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#compound-shapes)